# Is the device address of a buffer the same for different kernels/programs in OpenCL

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

When passing buffers as argument to OpenCL kernels, will the address of the buffer seen by the kernel code remains the same for the same buffer?

I used the code below to check and it seems that the address are indeed the same. However, I can't find anything in the standard to guarantee this.

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np

def main():
    ctx = cl.create_some_context()
    queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
    mf = cl.mem_flags
    buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY, 1000)
    buf2 = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_WRITE, 8)
    prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
    __kernel void
    get_addr(__global const int *in, __global long *out)
    {
        *out = (long)in;
    }
    """).build()

    knl = prg.get_addr
    knl.set_args(buf, buf2)
    cl.enqueue_task(queue, knl)

    b = np.empty([1], dtype=np.int64)
    cl.enqueue_copy(queue, b, buf2).wait()
    print(b[0])

    prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
    __kernel void
    get_addr(__global const int *in, __global long *out)
    {
        *out = (long)in;
    }
    """).build()
    knl = prg.get_addr
    knl.set_args(buf, buf2)
    cl.enqueue_task(queue, knl)

    b = np.empty([1], dtype=np.int64)
    cl.enqueue_copy(queue, b, buf2).wait()
    print(b[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The use case is that I am running a simulation using OpenCL which has many (arrays) of parameters. In order not having to pass these arrays around as arguments, I fill them in a struct and pass the pointer to the struct around instead. Since this struct will be used many times (and by all work items) I would like not having to fill it in every run of every kernels and would like to know if the pointers will change between different runs/work items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not guaranteed for OpenCL 1.x. This is why it is unsafe to store pointers in buffers. The runtime is allowed to move the allocation for each kernel launch. There is no guarantee that it will move it, and of course it is reasonable to expect that the buffer will not often need to move so it isn't surprising that you'd see the result you see. If you allocate a lot more buffers and cycle through them to force the runtime to move them around you will be more likely to see the issue.

For OpenCL 2.0 the shared virtual memory feature guarantees this by definition: the address couldn't be shared if it kept changing.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that SVM in OpenCL 2.0 shouldn't move and I was just hoping that there's similar guarantee (maybe with special flags) with OpenCL 1.x .... I guess I will just fill the struct in each run of the kernel. It doesn't seem to be the performance bottleneck anyway....